# How to create a global state in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state, react-state

Hope you're doing great :)

I'm working in a Favorite screen functionality, where I want to add the liked exercises to this screen. Everything went perfect, my problem is that the screens **don't rerender** when the button is clicked, only when the app is re-render. Here's the custom hook:

```
 const useStorage = (name, id, pratice, navigation) => {

  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState();

  const { storageDB } = useContext(StorageContext);

 
  //Favorites Actions
  const getFavorites = () => {
    const checkFavorites = storageDB.map((store) =>
      store.exercises.filter((exArray) => exArray.favorite)
    );
    const favoritesResult = checkFavorites.filter((ex) => ex.length !== 0);
    if (favoritesResult.length !== 0) return setFavorites(favoritesResult);
    return null;
  };

  const toggleFavorite = () => {
    //Find exercise
    const exerciseIndex = storageDB[topicIndex()].exercises.findIndex(
      (ex) => ex.id === id
    );

    //Topic > Exercise
    const exercise = storageDB[topicIndex()].exercises[exerciseIndex];

    //Toogle favorite
    exercise.favorite = !exercise.favorite;

    //Store in AsyncStorage
    storage.storeData(storageDB);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getFavorites();
  }, []);

  return {
    storageDB,
    getFavorites,
    toggleFavorite,
    favorites
  };
};
export default useStorage;
```

The hook params are meant to get the right exercise in the storage and gets called once in getFavorites().

Here's the FavoritesScreen:

```
const FavoritesScreen = () => {
  const { favorites } = useStorage();

  const Favorites = () => {
    if (favorites)
      return favorites.map((exArray) =>
        exArray.map((ex) => (
          <Card
            key={ex.id}
            exercise={ex}
            topicName={ex.topicName}
            onPress={() =>
              navigation.navigate("ExerciseDetails", {
                exercise,
                name: ex.topicName
              })
            }
          />
        ))
      );
    return <NotFound text="No favorite exercises" noImage />;
  };

  return (
    <Screen>
      <Image source={require("../assets/favorites.png")} style={styles.image} />
      <Title style={styles.title}>Favorites</Title>
      <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
        <SearchInput />
      </View>
      <Container scrollView>
        <Favorites />
      </Container>
    </Screen>
  );
};
```

I've tried so many things, used useEffect to listen to changes in the storageDB, even created a setStorageDB to access in all app, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a little difficult to follow your code and understand exactly what you are trying to do, however the screen is only going to rerender if a state variable is reassigned.  So favorites inside of useState will have to get reassigned to get a rerender.

For example toggleFavorite doesn't call setFavorites so it wont cause a screen to rerender, if you want the screen to rerender you will need to call setFavorites(newFavourites) where newFavorites has a different reference to the current favourites.

I hope this helps, usually I would include more code but as I said its a little tricky to work out exactly what you want, feel free to comment if you have further questions.

Comment: Hey Adam! I'm sorry for not putting more code, but I was concern about polluting the message with too much information. The project is entangled with useContext variables, custom hooks with AsyncStorage events, which is a bit messy to put all in here. But you're right. Thanks to you, I figured it out! I'll post the solution. Thank you for the sympathy! :)

Answer (score 0):

The flow I intended was:

1. When the user **likes the exercise**:

[image]

2. The **exercise object is updated** in the local storage and gets passed to Favorites Screen:

[image]

My problem was that when the user **unlikes the exercise**, it didn't update both components (Happiness and Favorites). I've solved it using **navigation.addListenter** and creating a local state for Favorite Screen (as mentioned by Adam).

Here's the line in **Favorites**:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener("focus", () => setFavorites(updatedFavorites()));
  }, []);
```

Here's the line in **Happiness**:

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener("focus", () => setKey((prevKey) => prevKey + 1));
  }, []);
```

Now every time we enter these components, they will re-render if there're changes :)